# Using Boost::json_parser() convert Json to XML with Shift JIS encoding

Tags: c++, boost, mfc, jsonparser, shift-jis

In my MFC project, I must receive string of json from webservice.And then I need to convert this json to XML format. So I try to use the **Boost C++** library for converting to XML file. Actually, a json will be converted to be property tree before converting to xml.
But I has a problem because it was converted to be incorrect words.
Because a string of json includes Japanese language. (as Shift-JIS encoding)

How do I fix it ?

Comment: JSON must be encoded using one of three UTF encodings. If your web service is returning Shift-JIS encoded JSON, fix the web service.

Comment: Also, consider using Boost JSON. Property Tree is not a JSON library (nor an XML library) and has several limitations

Comment: If a Boost Json isn't suitable for this problem. Would you recommend some library?

Comment: @Fameth google "nlohmann json"

Comment: @Jabberwocky The question was ill-posed. Boost JSON is *obviously* suited. It's Boot Property Tree that is **not**.